# Condtional replacement of values based on columns in two dataframes

Tags: r, formatting, conditional-formatting

I have two data frames below with the same columns row names. I want to change the values to NA in df_B based foe every "1" in df_A. See "GOAL" for example of what I'm hoping to achieve.

Thanks!

Date Frame A

```
 ID  x1 x2 x3
  A  NA  1 NA
  B  NA  1  1
  C  NA  1 NA
```

Data Frame B

```
 ID x1 x2 x3
  A  0  9  0
  B  10 4  6
  C  0  5  5
```

GOAL

```
 ID x1 x2 x3
  A  0  NA 0
  B  10 NA NA
  C  0  NA 5
```

Any ideas on how I might do this? I've tried using ifelse functions and subsetting to no avail.
Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a logical matrix with the first data except the first column by checking if the elements are equal to 1.  Use that to subset the values in df2 without the first column and assign them to `NA`

```
df2[-1][(df1[-1] == 1) & !is.na(df1[-1])] <- NA
```

As there are `NA` elements in 'df1', we can use `is.na` to check for elements that are not an `NA` and is 1

-output

```
df2
#  ID x1 x2 x3
#1  A  0 NA  0
#2  B 10 NA NA
#3  C  0 NA  5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), x1 = c(NA, NA, NA), x2 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L), x3 = c(NA, 1L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), x1 = c(0L, 10L, 0L), x2 = c(9L, 
4L, 5L), x3 = c(0L, 6L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```